# How to know if a text is really a text patch?

Tags: regex

I'm using Google's [diff_match_patch](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/wiki/API) to diff and patch text in a REST-api. Sometimes the data sent to my service is plain text, sometimes it's a patch. How do I know the difference (for sure)?

I suppose I can use a regex to accomplish this. Perhaps there are one out there allready I can use? One that always matches the pattern of a patch and not something a user could have written...

Comment: [Take a look at his, maybe will explain it better.](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/wiki/Plaintext)

Comment: Try run `patch` on it and fall back to plain text? Regex is not a particularly well-suited tool for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

A diff/patch seem to always start like this:

```
@@ -84,16 +84,19 @@...
```

So a regex for this could be:

```
/^@@ \-[0-9]+,[0-9]+ \+[0-9]+,[0-9]+ @@.+/
```

If I find a match on this pattern I go ahead and assume it's a patch...